# Enable and Disable manual proxy setting in Windows 8

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, proxy

I want to enable and disable manual proxy setup in windows 7,8 and 8. I want to toggle the manual proxy setup option using command script. I want to create a .bat file using command line and whenever I click on that .bat file, the manual proxy setup option will be toggled. I don't know the command for doing my job. I want to know the command for this job. 
[image: Required toggle option is marked]

Comment: This question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Quirk this question is better placed in the super user group, but at the same time, users are drawn more often to StackOverflow and get discouraged when they don't find the answer.

Here is something I came up with, also my taught process:

1. all of Windows configurations that are flags or simple values are kept in the registry
2. you can manipulate the registry with the `REG` command
3. `REG /?` shows you what you can do
4. with `regedit` you can search the registry `(F3)` for your proxy host name

   > *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings*[image]
5. once you found the `REG_KEY` you are ready to write your script

in conclusion:

here is your 'command' for enabling your proxy:

> REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d **1** /f

here is your 'command' for disabling your proxy:

> REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d **0** /f

It works, the value is set, but I am pretty sure your Network Settings Window does not get the update until the next time you open it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to enable and disable manual proxy setup

To enable:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy:80
```

To disable:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

To show the current settings:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this same way and it shows in the last command too. But the issue is when I open the settings it's not showing. Can you please help me with this? It's quite urgent for me.